# Is there an easier way to get a list of columns in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

I really like how the DB table column names show up in intellisense when using `sequelize`.

Column names are visible in intellisense right before you create `where`, for example:

```
const res = await MyTableModel.findAll({
  where: {
    // intellisense here
  }
});

console.log(res.map((item) => item.dataValues));
```

But as you know, `attributes` is sometimes simply an array of strings, so intellisense doesn't work. So I either move to another document to refer to the column name, or create and delete a temporary `where`.

1. Get column by IntelliSense.

```
  where: { att1 }
```

2. Add quote.(block to `ctrl`+`shift`, `right arrow` and quote.

```
  where: { 'att1' }
```

3. Repeat.

```
  where: { 'att1', 'att2, 'att3, 'att4, 'att5' }
```

4. Edit to array.

```
  attributes: [ 'att1', 'att2, 'att3, 'att4, 'att5' ]
```

I felt I was doing something stupid.

So I looked for another way. And I found `getAttributes`.

```
MyTableModel.getAttributes(). // intellisense here
```

It's better. In `where`, column names and others were mixed, but not in `getAttributes`. Of course, more post-edits are needed.

Is there an easier way I'm missing?

Comment: This is not related to your question, but have you tried Prisma? Sequelize is a poorly designed library, and Prisma is so much better.

Comment: I've heard that ```prisma``` has serious performance issues. What is the performance difference from ```sequelize``` in practice?

Comment: I don't think you're basing that on anything? I wouldn't expect the performance to be significantly different between the two. Sequelize is just very painful to use and a poor abstraction over SQL

Comment: I've only been looking for it for a very short time, but ```prisma``` seems handy. Do you know of any performance benchmarks?